# how do i detect scroll position with jquery without binding to scroll events?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a mockup elevator, but there are two things causing trouble.

1. Updating `.floor-number` to reflect the current floor.

   It seems I should change `.floor-number` with the content property like so:

   ```
   .content-property {
   visibility: hidden;
   }
   .content-property::after {
   visibility: visible;
   content: "3";
   }
   ```

   And then detect when the user has stopped scrolling and add the above css with jQuery's addClass. But that's really unwieldy.
2. Displaying the green `.up` indicator when the elevator is going up and the red `.down` indicator when the elevator is going down.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/5rzzbunk/2/

Comment: So what do you want to bind it to?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to detect scroll you'll have to bind it. But performance issues (if there would be any) can be limited by setting a timeout and only checking so many times a second when scroll is initiated. And then clear the timeout when the user has not scrolled for a certain amount of ms.

Comment: I created a small pen to demonstrate the amount of scroll events if you're interested, @sabaeus. Doesn't seem to be very inefficient though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first part you can simply use:

```
var current_floor = $(this).html();
$('.floor-number').html(current_floor);
```

This will update `.floor-number` to reflect the current floor.

---

To detect the scroll, you will need to use the `scroll()` function:

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
           $('.up').fadeOut(100);
           $('.down').fadeIn(100);
       }
       else {
           $('.down').fadeOut(100);
           $('.up').fadeIn(100);
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}());
```

---

**[Here is an Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5rzzbunk/4/)** which covers both parts of your problem.

Comment: I'd use a fade instead of a hide/show. Or not set a time parameter. Looks jumpy otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has my upvote but just out of curiosity I wrote a little function that calculates the amount of scroll events fired. Results vary across browser :

- Firefox around 60 (probably higher than the rest because of default smooth scroll)
- Chrome and Opera a little under 40
- Internet Explorer about 20

On my setup at least...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbNOdG

May be connected with display framerate. If it's plugged into that it shouldn't be much of a resource hogger anyway. But have a look and decide for oneself if it's worth limiting down.

```
var i, first = true, then, finished, elapsed, triggers;

$(window).scroll(function() {

if (first) {
i = 0;
first = false;
then = new Date().getTime();
}

i++;
clearTimeout(finished);
checkScroll();

function checkScroll() {

finished = setTimeout(function() {
elapsed = new Date().getTime()-then-150;
triggers = Math.round(1000/(elapsed/i));
first = true;
$('#log').html(triggers + '</br>events per second');
}, 150);
}
});
```

Still, it could be a single action per mousewheel event (which should default to scroll) if this neat extension is used :

https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

```
$(window).mousewheel(function(turn, delta) {

if (delta == -1) {
$('.up').fadeOut(100);
$('.down').fadeIn(100);
}
else {
$('.up').fadeIn(100);
$('.down').fadeOut(100);
}
});
```

The `wheel` event could replace this when Opera starts supporting it.